# How to extract the year from a URL path using REGEXP_EXTRACT in Google Data Studio?

Tags: regex, uri, looker-studio, re2

I'm building out a Google Data Studio dashboard and I need to create a calculated field for the year a post was published. The year is in the URI path, but I'm not sure how to extract it using `REGEXP_EXTRACT`.  I've tried a number of solutions proposed on here but none of them seem to work on Data Studio.

In short, I have a URI like this: `/theme/2019/jan/blog-post-2019/`

How do I use the `REGEXP_EXTRACT` function to get the first 2019 after `theme/` and before `/jan`?

Comment: Please share the current code to see where you are stuck.

Comment: Don't have it because that's where I'm stuck. This is all I have: REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page, '(\d{4}[^/.*]*)') and it isn't working as it is capturing the second occurrence of the year as well and produces an error in Data Studio.

Comment: Try `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page, '/([0-9]{4})/')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page, 'theme\/([0-9]{4})\/[a-z]{3}\/')
```

where:

- `theme\/` means literally "theme/";
- `([0-9]{4})` is a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) containing 4 characters from 0 to 9 (i.e. four digits);
- `\/[a-z]{3}\/` means a slash, followed by 3 lowercase letters (supposing that you want the regex to match all the months), followed by another slash. If you want something more restrictive, try with `\/(?:jan|feb|mar|...)\/` for the last part.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cxSWMZ/1).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, I think you only want to extract the year between the string. The following will achieve that for you.

fit the query as per your needs

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM Sample_table
 WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, "(?<=\/theme\/)(?<year>\d{4})(?=\/[a-zA-Z]{3})")
```